# pivotting a list of data frames and merging them

Tags: r, list, pivot, tidyverse

I have a list of 3 dataframes that share some rows and columns

**DATA**

```
all_data <- list(questionnaireA = structure(list(name = structure(2:1, .Label = c("James", 
          "Shawn"), class = "factor"), banana = c(1, 0), grapes = c(1, 
          1), orange = c("AB", 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
          -2L)), questionnaireB = structure(list(name = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Chris", 
          "James"), class = "factor"), orange = c(1, 0), banana = c(1, 
          0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), questionnaireC = structure(list(
          name = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Donald", "James", "Shawn"
          ), class = "factor"), banana = c(1, 0, 0), raisins = c(1, 
          1, 1), grapes = c(1, 1, 0), cake = c(0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

> ```
> $questionnaireA
>    name banana grapes orange
> 1 Shawn      1      1     AB
> 2 James      0      1      1
>
> $questionnaireB
>    name orange banana
> 1 James      1      1
> 2 Chris      0      0
>
> $questionnaireC
>     name banana raisins grapes cake
> 1  Shawn      1       1      1    0
> 2  James      0       1      1    1
> 3 Donald      0       1      0    0
> ```

```
library(tidyverse)
map(all_data, ~ .x %>%
    pivot_longer(cols=-name, names_to="fruit"))
```

1. Am not sure how to rename the value to the name of the dataframe.
2. I don't know how to join the values and union the name fruit pair.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just added the expected output. So I would like to add the values I get from pivot_longer as column to the union of all the name+fruit pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we follow the similar option as in OP's attempted method, i.e. reshape to 'long' format each of the datasets in the `list`, then loop with `imap`, create the name of the `list1` element as new column, use `pivot_longer` to reshape into 'long' format, then create a sequence column by group and reshape into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
imap_dfr(all_data, ~
                   .x %>% 
                      mutate(grp = .y) %>%
                      pivot_longer(cols = -c(name, grp), 
                         names_to = "fruit", values_to = "Value")) %>% 
   #group_by(name, grp, fruit) %>% 
   #mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Value)
```

---

Or do this more efficiently, by binding all the datasets to a single data with `bind_cols`, do the `pivot_longer` while removing the missing values with `value_drop_na = TRUE` and then do the same as in the above solution

```
bind_rows(all_data, .id = 'grp') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(-name, -grp), names_to = "fruit", 
         values_to = "Value", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    # sequence column creation is not really required for the example
    # as there are no duplicates
    #group_by(name, grp, fruit) %>% 
    #mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Value)
```

#### Update

Based on the new data with some mix in column types, if we need to have the values like "AB" remain as such, it needs to be converted to `character` class

```
imap_dfr(all_data, ~
               .x %>% 
                  mutate_at(-1, as.character) %>% 
                  mutate(grp = .y) %>% 
                  pivot_longer(cols = -c(name, grp), names_to = "fruit",
                    values_to = "Value")) %>% 
       pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Value)
```

Or an efficient approach similar to the `bind_rows` earlier (but it can't be done here because the column types are different)

```
map_dfr(all_data, ~
         .x %>%
            mutate_at(-1, as.character), .id = 'grp') %>%  
    pivot_longer(cols = c(-name, -grp), names_to = "fruit", 
          values_to = "Value", values_drop_na = TRUE)  %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Value)
```

Comment: just one small issue! Is there a way to force these dataframe numeric values into character? I got an error saying: `Error: Column \`C_BIG\` can't be converted from character to numeric` during pivot_longer

Comment: @user171558  Is it based on the same example or different one (as I am not able to reproduce the error)

Comment: @user171558  Can you try  `bind_rows(all_data, .id = 'grp')  %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(-name, -grp), names_to = "fruit", values_to = "Value", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Value)`

Comment: I made a modification to the sample data! Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: @user171558  Do you  want the "AB" to remain as "AB" or as `NA` i.e. do you want to have a numeric column or character